# How to add the helper to `underscorejs` template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am trying to add the helper function to my `underscore` template. But I am not able to do this. any one can please correct me?

here is my tempalate:

```
<script type="text/template" id="table">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <% _.each(obj.titles, function(item){ %>
                    <td><%= item.label %>
                <% }); %>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</script>
```

Here is my js:

```
var viewHelper = {
    getProperty: function(propertyName) {
        console.log('getProperty ' + propertyName);
        return propertyName;
    }
};

var obj = {
    "titles" : [
            {"label" : "-----Totals for Month----   "},
            {"label":"-----Previous Year-----"}
    ]
};

var template = _.template($('#table').html());

var html =  _.extend(obj, viewHelper);

$('body').html(template(html));
```

But I am not able to get any call in to my helper function at all..

please update in to my fiddle;

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcr45c9z/)

Comment: Your template doesn't use `getProperty`, have you tried calling `getProperty` in your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine with your code. You just have to use the function in your template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="table">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <% _.each(obj.titles, function(item){ %>
                    <td><%= item.label %></td>
                <% }); %>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <% _.each(obj.titles, function(item){ %>
                    <td><%= getProperty(item.label) %></td>
                <% }); %>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
 </script>
```

This is a working plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/akeiPbQoZBjzgBsEykTi?p=preview